# Two apparently equivalent mappings, one works the other doesn't

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc

I'm using the easymotion plugin and mapping my arrow keys to do calls to easymotion. Concretely:

```
map <down> <Plug>(easymotion-w)
map <left> <Plug>(easymotion-F)
map <right> <Plug>(easymotion-bd-f)
map <up> <Plug>(easymotion-B)
```

This works as intended. Now I want it to work also in insert mode so I added:

```
imap <down> <Esc><down>
imap <left> <Esc><left>
imap <right> <Esc><right>
imap <up> <Esc><up>
```

Now in insert mode *down* and *up* work like the default keys (moving up and down) whereas *right* *left* have the intended behaviour. However, to me they seem equivalent mappings.

I've tried changing to `imap <down> <Esc>dd`, still does the default behaviour. If I put `imap <left> <Esc>dd` it deletes the line. So it may not be related to easymotion in particular.

**Question 1** What is happening and how can I solve it?

**Question 2**: is this the most elegant/correct way to do mappings?

*Note:* at first I thought it may be affected by the time it  takes to go from Insert to Normal mode, so I added the following piece of code that solves it:

```
set timeout " Do time out on mappings and others
set timeoutlen=2000 " Wait {num} ms before timing out a mapping
   "when press Esc to leave Ins mode it no longer takes a second
   "or another keystroke to leave Ins mode completely and update
   "the satus line.
set ttimeoutlen=0
augroup FastEscape:
    autocmd!
    au InsertEnter * set timeoutlen=0
    au InsertLeave * set timeoutlen=1000
augroup END
```

Comment: Another plugin is probably changing the `<up>` and `<down>` keys on `InsertEnter`.  In insert mode, type: `<c-o>:verbose imap <down>`.

Comment: @TommyA thanks! that's exactly what was happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @TommyA pointed out in the comments, a plugin was changing `<up>` and `<down>`. Turned out to be 'youcompleteme', in /autoload/youcompleteme.vim. There `<up>` `<down>` aren't explicitely mentioned, but they are called because they are part of the `g:ycm_key_list_select_completion` and `g:ycm_key_list_previous_completion` lists. Those lists were defined in youcompleteme/plugin/youcompleteme.vim, editing them solved the issue.